# Вычислительная геометрия, уравнение прямой

Tags: c++, python, алгоритм, вычислительная-геометрия

Имеется ли у кого-то пример кода работающего с полуплоскостями. В частности по уравнению прямой *ax+by+c=0*, определяющий полуплоскость, в которой однозначно *ax+by+c>=0*. Нужен просто способ это делать, мои наработки только путали, я обрабатывал все возможные наклоны прямой (а точнее диапазоны), и выходило ужасно много кода.

Или если проще то помогите с вот этой задачей - https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/problems/2960. (Идейно, я прекрасно понимаю, что от меня хотят). Написал преподсчет, но когда доходит до работы с самой прямой, и тем как понимать, какая полуплоскость у меня обрабатывается чисто на уровне реализации, я не могу придумать. Уверен, там какой-то очень короткий и простой код, а не те 12 if-ов, с вложенностями которые я городил. 
Еще раз уточнню, я не прошу за меня ее решить, я хочу увидеть пример реализации, ибо самому не хватает ума это сделать, только на полный разбор случаев. (код понимаю на js, c#, c++, python, php)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87553/discussion-on-question-by-berestovsky----).

Answer (score 1):

Закономерность такая -  значение выражения `-Sign(c) * (ax+by+c) < 0` отрицательно для тех точек, которые находятся по одну сторону от прямой с началом координат `(0, 0)`, и положительно для точек, находящихся по разные стороны от прямой с началом координат. (Проще приводить уравнение прямой к виду с отрицательным c)

Пример: прямая `y=2x+1` или `2x-y+1=0`. Точка `(1,10)` выше прямой, а начало координат ниже, выражение с учётом знака `c` даёт положительный результат

Comment: Значение выражения `ax+by+c` положительно для тех точек, которые лежат с той же стороны от прямой, в которую указывает вектор нормали `(a, b)`.

Comment: @AnT И чтобы узнать, та ли это сторона, можно делать кросс-продукт с направляющим вектором или дот-продукт с нормалью, в результате выражение будет тем же самым. А направление вектора нормали (которых два) зависит и от знака c, что учтено в формуле